# TYPO3 9.5.x: After upgrading from Version 6 LTS to 7 LTS to 9.5.3, the page tree collapses every time

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-9.x

After upgrading the typo3 from 6 LTS to 9.5.3, the page tree is closed after every action oder new login, thats really annoying, especially if you have a big page tree. I reproduced the bug at another typo3 project, also from 6 to 9.

Comment: Did you try to clear BE user setting? Also try clear your browser local storage. If this will not help, you may create an issue on forge.typo3.org

Comment: thank you, this worked for me